# Use AndroidX artifacts checkbox missing from Android Studio (Version 3.6.1) when creating a new project?

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx

A checkbox called use `AndroidX` artifacts is seen in `Android Studio` when creating a new project (screenshot below).

[image]

But in my case, it's missing. **Android Studio version 3.6.1** (screenshot below).

[image]

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: That AndroidX is now the new default

Comment: Now Androidx is the **default** and the option is replaced by *"Use legacy android.support libraries"* if you want to use support libraries instead of androidx libraries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In 3.6.1, `Androidx` is enabled by default along with `enableJetifier`.

You can verify it in the `gradle.properties` files with values as

```
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true
```